# How to use JSONP to make AJAX request to different site on network

Tags: multisite, ajax

I am trying to get buddypress avatars on a network's main site from a sub-site. The way buddypress does avatars is really involved with loops and fallbacks etc and doesn't consist of any database calls, which would have been straightforward.

Instead I thought maybe I will create a function on my main site to output the user's avatar and then grab it with AJAX. But the cross-domain policy is in effect and I'm having difficulty understanding how to implement JSONP to get around it.

My javascript looks like this:

```
$('.external-avatar').each(function(){
            var user_id = $(this).data('user_id');
            $.ajax({  
              type: 'POST',  
              url: vars.rootAjaxurl,  
                  data: {  
                  action: 'bp_cross_site_avatar',  
                  user_id: user_id,  
              },  
              success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest, user_id){  
                  $(".external-avatar.user-"+user_id).attr('src', data);  
              },  
              error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
                // alert(errorThrown);  
              }  
            });  
        });
```

Is there a way to get a request like this to work?

Answer (score 1):

There's two parts to this, the javascript ajax call needs specific variables included:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: SSL_Ajax.ajaxurl,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "jsonp",              
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {
                action : 'ajaxSSL',
                ajaxSSLNonce : SSL_Ajax.ajaxSSLNonce,
                input : $('input[name=title]').val()
            },

            success: function( data ) {
                console.log( 'success' );
                console.log( data );
            },

            complete: function( data ) {
                console.log( 'complete' );
                console.log( data );
            },

            error: function( data ) {
                console.log( 'error' );
                console.log( data );
            }
        });
```

The important variables here for jsonp are `cache`,`dataType`, and `crossDomain`. **Note:** when your dataType is jsonp it creates an additional varible 'callback'. Also, by it's very nature, jsonp is `type` GET.

The other important thing to note is in the `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}` and `wp_ajax_{action}` actions you need to include the callback and access-control header:

```
header("content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['callback']) . '(' . $response . ')';

// IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
exit;
```

I wrote a about [using jsonp in WordPress](http://www.jackreichert.com/2014/11/04/using-jsonp-in-wordpress-development-the-quick-and-dirty-quickstart-guide/) if you want more details.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the blog ID of the sub-site to your AJAX callback handler, use `switch_to_blog()` there and get the data you need.

This way, you can stay on the same site with all front-end processing, while you get the information from the other site with PHP.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize you could do that.. that way I don't even need ajax at all. oh man.

Comment: Just reading and it says switch_to_blog() doesn't cover plugins, though :/

Comment: What? The function changes the current blog context, no matter where it has been called. Plugin or core is not relevant in this case.

Comment: The docs say "Things that aren't switched: plugins" with reference to [this discussion](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14941)

Comment: @Damon is right, switch_to_blog will only switch DB tables references, the same plugins will still need to be active on the requested site  for it to work.  so this is a limited solution.  Many plugins are not multisite compatible, such as mailpoet's API for example.